# Fast Python algorithm for finding the path that maximize the sum of the changes of each move

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, undirected-graph

Say I have a undirected graph (can be cyclic or acyclic), where each node is asigned with an integer state. I want to find the path that:

1. goes through every node but only once
2. doesn't need to go through every edge
3. maximize the sum of the state changes of each move

As an example, I have a cyclic graph -5-4-5-7-2- (first 5 and last 2 are connected). If we start from the first 5 and end at the last 2, the sum of the changes of each move will be `-1 + 1 + 2 + (-5) = -3`. The graph can be described by an adjacency matrix as follows:

```
import numpy as np
node_states = [5, 4, 5, 7, 2]
# Adjacency matrix
               #5 4 5 7 2
am = np.array([[0,1,0,0,1], # 5
               [1,0,1,0,0], # 4
               [0,1,0,1,0], # 5
               [0,0,1,0,1], # 7
               [1,0,0,1,0]])# 2
```

The expected output is

```
max_delta_sum_path = [2, 5, 4, 5, 7]
```

where the path has the largest sum `3 + (-1) + 1 + 2 = 5`

Anyone knows if there is any relatively fast algorithm that can automatically find this path?

Comment: Finding the path which goes through every node but only once is already a [fun (aka NP-complete)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
node_states = [5, 4, 5, 7, 2]
# Adjacency matrix
               #5 4 5 7 2
am = np.array([[0,1,0,0,1], # 5
               [1,0,1,0,0], # 4
               [0,1,0,1,0], # 5
               [0,0,1,0,1], # 7
               [1,0,0,1,0]])# 2

for i in range(len(node_states)):
    for j in range(len(node_states)):
        if am[i][j] == 1:
            am[i][j] = node_states[i] - node_states[j] # go through ever entry in every list, and if it is 1 replace it with the traversal cost
"""
am =    [[ 0  1  0  0  3]
         [-1  0 -1  0  0]
         [ 0  1  0 -2  0]
         [ 0  0  2  0  5]
         [-3  0  0 -5  0]]
"""

from itertools import permutations
def largest_sum(node_states, am):
    largest = None
    largest_journey = None
    traversal_list = list(permutations(range(len(node_states)), len(node_states))) # store all possible permutations of node_states indexes
    for trav in traversal_list: # go through each permuatation
        costs = [] # track the cost of each traversal
        for i in range(len(trav)):
            if i == 0: # there are one less traversals than nodes so we are ignoring the first node
                continue
            if am[trav[i]][trav[i-1]] == 0: # traversal cannot happen if the traversal has no adjacency
                continue
            costs.append(am[trav[i]][trav[i-1]]) # use the updated am matrix to get our costs, and store them here
        if len(costs) == len(node_states) - 1: # if one less traversal was made than we have nodes, we know all nodes were visited
            costs_sum = sum(costs) # sum the costs for our total of travel
            if largest is None or largest < costs_sum: # only keep this total if it was bigger than our old total
                largest = costs_sum # track the new total
                largest_trav = list(map(lambda x: node_states[x], trav)) # change our array of indexes (trav) into an array of node values
    return largest_trav # when the looping is done, return our total

out = largest_sum(node_states, am)
print(out)
```

Output:

```txt
[2, 5, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

- replace each undirected link with two directed, costed links.  e.g a link between nodes of state 5 and 7 would be replaced by two links with costs of +2 and -2.
- add value to cost of every link that will make all link costs positive
- find cost of most expensive link and subtract from every link cost
- multiply every link cost by -1
- apply travelling salesman algorithm

So, for your example:

```
0 -> 1 cost -1 converts to 6

0 -> 4 cost -3 converts to 8

1 -> 0 cost 1 converts to 4

1 -> 2 cost 1 converts to 4

2 -> 1 cost -1 converts to 6

2 -> 3 cost 2 converts to 3

3 -> 2 cost -2 converts to 7

3 -> 4 cost -5 converts to 10

4 -> 0 cost 3 converts to 2

4 -> 3 cost 5 converts to 0
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of algorithms for asymmetrical TSP problem? In my case, the number of nodes is very small (<=5) so I would expect something not too complicated.

Comment: With such a small node count you might as well do a simple brute force search